# Who was the guy in the scene after the credits in The Avengers?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

After the credits roll on *The Avengers*, there is a brief scene that appears to hint at who the next villain will be. I thought it looked kind of like the Red Skull, but others I saw it with disagreed.

Who was it?

Comment: I thought he looked like kang the conqueror.

Comment: I thought it was red skull. Due to the fact that he disapeared at the end of Captain America, and the reference betweek Lokis staff and a hydra weapon.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I just got back from the film, and the mid-credits scene villain is indeed [Thanos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos).  He's a cosmic-level villain who seeks to control the universe.  The idea that the entire film's plot was just a scheme his minions were working on for him is a pretty great introduction for him.  His desire for objects of power suggests that his goal was to get the "Tesseract", which in the comics are called [Cosmic Cubes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_cube).

In addition, his Chitauri minion referred to attacking Earth as 'courting Death', which is a reference to [Thanos having a thing for Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos#The_Infinity_Saga).

Comment: Just as a late note, Thanos is also a bastardization of the Greek word for death, and Thanatos is the name for death in many novels and fictionalizations.

Answer (score 13):

I will confirm this when I see the movie later tonight, but preliminary research indicates that this villain is [Thanos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos)

> Feige revealed on an Empire magazine podcast that the "master" in the post credits scene is Thanos.

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_%282012_film%29#cite_note-EmpirePodcast-171)

Comment: Definitely looks a lot like the image you linked. I thought he was a little more red in the film, but it might have been a trick of the lighting.

Comment: @Sterno After seeing it myself, I see.  He was rather *red* when it seems he's *blue* in these pictures.  But hey it was a spectacular movie.

Answer (score 4):

The guy in the scene after the credits, is The Mad Titan, THANOS. One of the most powerful beings (villains) in the Marvel Universe.