# To whom is the Chitauri mastermind talking in the beginning?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-avengers

I'm not sure if it's really the Chitauri mastermind, but bear with me.

In the opening of *The Avengers* we see some blue glimmer, some Chitauri, Loki's hands receiving the scepter/spear. All overlaid by these lines

> He *(meaning Loki)* is ready to lead
>   And our force, our Chitauri, will follow
>   A world will be his
>   The universe, **yours.**

Who is this "you", the omniscient voice is talking to? Who did the Chitauri strike a deal with?

Comment: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/who-was-the-guy-in-the-scene-after-the-credits-in-the-avengers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Thanos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos).

Check the end credits scene, and you can see him. I don't think he was named in "The Avengers", but we do learn his name in "Guardians of the Galaxy".

Comment: Thak you, Unfortunately the end credits aren't available to me, but the wiki page seems to support you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Ronan. He states their master knows the workings of the tesseract like the no other. That seems to be Thanos. I think they're talking to Ronan to try and recruit him to the side of Thanos.